# How to change the language at runtime in python/gettext?

Tags: python, gettext

This is my first use of gettext in Python (and gettext generally). I understood many things and my test application works well: one command line parameter changes the language of output messages.

Now I'd like to let the user change the language at startup.

I know I can load many translations and install one of them at run-time, however many strings are already translated with the old language and will not change again.

Any simple solution?

```
import gettext

language = "it"
t_en = gettext.translation("messages", localedir="locale", languages=["en"], fallback=True)
t_it = gettext.translation("messages", localedir="locale", languages=["it"], fallback=True)


def language_install():
    if language == "it":
        t_it.install()
    else:
        t_en.install()

language_install()
main_menu = [_("First item"), _("Second item"), _("Switch language"), _("Exit")]

while True:
    print("MAIN MENU")
    print("---------")
    for (n, item) in enumerate(main_menu):
        print("{:d}: ".format(n + 1) + item)
    print("")
    ans = input(_("Select an item") + ": ")
    if ans == "4":
        break
    elif ans == "3":
        if language == "en":
            language = "it"
        else:
            language = "en"
        language_install()
    else:
        print(_("You have selected item") + " " + ans)
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906944/approaches-to-changing-language-at-runtime-with-python-gettext), would flag as dupe but can't due to bounty.

Answer (score -1):

for simple uses (like yours) that will work:

```
import gettext

language = "it"
translators = {
    "it": gettext.translation("messages", localedir="locale", languages=["it"], fallback=True),
    "en": gettext.translation("messages", localedir="locale", languages=["en"], fallback=True),
}


class LazyStr:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.value = s

    def __str__(self):
        return translators[language].gettext(self.value)

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self) + str(other)


_ = LazyStr

main_menu = [_("First item"), _("Second item"), _("Switch language"), _("Exit")]

while True:
    print("MAIN MENU")
    print("---------")
    for (n, item) in enumerate(main_menu):
        print("{:d}: ".format(n + 1) + str(item))
    print("")
    ans = input(_("Select an item") + ": ")
    if ans == "4":
        break
    elif ans == "3":
        if language == "en":
            language = "it"
        else:
            language = "en"
    else:
        print(_("You have selected item") + " " + ans)
```

Answer (score -2):

**The problem you're facing is because** the translation of the strings is done at the moment when the strings are defined, not when they are used. This means that when you change the language and reinstall the `gettext` function, the strings that have already been defined won't be translated again.

**A simple solution to this problem** is to delay the translation until the moment when the strings are used. This can be done by storing the untranslated strings and the `gettext` function, and calling the function every time you need the translated string.

**Here's how you can do it:**

```
import gettext

language = "it"
t_en = gettext.translation("messages", localedir="locale", languages=["en"], fallback=True)
t_it = gettext.translation("messages", localedir="locale", languages=["it"], fallback=True)

def language_install():
    if language == "it":
        t_it.install()
    else:
        t_en.install()

language_install()

# Store untranslated strings and gettext function
main_menu = [gettext.gettext("First item"), gettext.gettext("Second item"), gettext.gettext("Switch language"), gettext.gettext("Exit")]

while True:
    print("MAIN MENU")
    print("---------")
    for (n, item) in enumerate(main_menu):
        # Translate the string at the moment of use
        print("{:d}: ".format(n + 1) + _(item))
    print("")
    ans = input(_("Select an item") + ": ")
    if ans == "4":
        break
    elif ans == "3":
        if language == "en":
            language = "it"
        else:
            language = "en"
        language_install()
    else:
        print(_("You have selected item") + " " + ans)
```